# Testing new data on a trained LGBM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm, countvectorizer

I am a newbie to ML, and trying to replicate a price optimization solution available at https://www.kaggle.com/tunguz/more-effective-ridge-lgbm-script-lb-0-44823?source=post_page-------

I followed the same code as given, and then trying to test it on a new data. However, it is not predicting the price correctly at all. I am making sure I save the trained model/vectors, load it fresh and transform the new data as per the model requirements, similar to as done to the training set.

The issue is, if my new data is exactly same as my Test dataset (600k + rows) used during testing the model, then it is returning me exact correct results as during test prediction. But if I use only, example, first 10 rows of it, then it is not matching the existing results at all, even though I am transforming the features through saved vectors.

```
#below is while training the model
cvname = CountVectorizer(min_df=NAME_MIN_DF)
X_name = cvname.fit_transform(merge['name'])
pickle.dump(cvname, open("namevector.pkl", "wb"))
.
.
.
.
#after completing the training, and loading the new data
handle_missing_inplace(mytest)
cutting(mytest)
to_categorical(mytest)

cv1 = pickle.load(open("namevector.pkl", "rb"))
X_name1 = cv1.transform(mytest['name'])
cv2 = pickle.load(open("categoryvector.pkl", "rb"))
X_category1 = cv2.transform(mytest['category_name'])
tv1 = pickle.load(open("descriptionvector.pkl", "rb"))
X_description1 = tv1.transform(mytest['item_description'])
lb1 = pickle.load(open("brandvector.pkl", "rb"))
X_brand1 = lb1.transform(mytest['brand_name'])
t1 = pd.get_dummies(mytest[['item_condition_id', 'shipping']],sparse=True)
X_dummies1 = csr_matrix(t1.values.astype('int64'))

sparse_merge1 = hstack((X_dummies1, X_description1, X_brand1, X_category1, X_name1)).tocsr()
X_test1 = sparse_merge1
my_pred = pkl_bst1.predict(X_test1)
mysubmission['price'] = np.expm1(my_pred)
```

Can anyone please let me know what am I missing? The model worked fine on train and test dataset, but not on new data, or even small subset of Test dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually called [**overfitting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). Or perhaps it is [**underfitting**](https://www.datarobot.com/wiki/underfitting/). As any other ML algorithm, LGBM is susceptible to both.

Meaning the model does very well on training and test data, ***but perform poorly on new data***. [The model is not **generalizing** well](https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/challenges-of-generalization-in-machine-learning), it is just memorizing the training data.
There are some suggestions [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html#deal-with-over-fitting) on how to deal with overfitting on LGBM in particular, but there is a *lot of information about the issue in general* you should take the time to read. Google is the usual starting point.

Collecting more data is sometimes the way to deal with the problem. Hundred of thousands, millions. Machine learning is a data hungry business.

You will have to tweak some model parameters and do a lot of training *until your predictions start to improve*, if ever. It is called [***parameter tuning***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization).

That's the tough side of ML.

Don't get discouraged though.